# Find the determinants of the given matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider scalars $a,b,c,d,e,f$ such that

$\det\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & 1 & d\\
b & 1 & e\\
c & 1 & f\\ \end{array} \right) = 7$ and $\det\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & 1 & d\\
b & 2 & e\\
c & 3 & f\\ \end{array} \right) = 11$

What is $\det\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & 3 & d\\
b & 3 & e\\
c & 3 & f\\ \end{array} \right)$ and $\det\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & 3 & d\\
b & 4 & e\\
c & 5 & f\\ \end{array} \right)$?

For the first one, I was thinking that the determinant would be $3\cdot 7 = 21$, and I think the determinant of the second one would still just be $11$ (since it's just a multiple of the second determinant matrix). Does this seem right? How can I solve these kinds of problems?

Comment: I think that the second one will be $11+2\cdot7=11+14=25$...

Comment: @Larara What makes you think that?

Comment: Well, if you use [Laplace's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) you'll see that, for example, the first term (that multiplying $a$), will be $a\cdot(4\cdot f - 5\cdot e)=a\cdot((2+2)\cdot f - (3+2)\cdot e)=a\cdot(2\cdot f + 3\cdot e) + 2\cdot a\cdot(f-e)$, and the first term in the previous sum is the term multiplying $a$ in the matrix whose determinant is 11; and the second term in the previous sum is 2 times the term multiplying $a$ in matrix whose determinant is 7. And the terms multiplying $b$ and $c$ will be analogous.

Answer (score 1):

Givan an $n \times n$ matrix $A = (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{n})$, where $a_{i}$ are column vectors. There are identities
$$det(a_1, \ldots, ca_i, \ldots, a_n) = cdet(A)$$ and
$$det(a_1, \ldots, a_{i-1}, a_i + v, a_{i+1} \ldots, a_n) = det(A) + det(a_1, \ldots, a_{i-1}, v, a_{i+1}, \ldots, a_n)$$, where $v$ is a column vector.

Therefore, returning to your questions,
$$det\begin{pmatrix}
a & 3 & d\\
b & 3 & e\\
c & 3 & f
\end{pmatrix} = 3 \cdot 7 = 21$$
and
$$det\begin{pmatrix}
a & 3 & d\\
b & 4 & e\\
c & 5 & f
\end{pmatrix} = 2 \cdot 7 + 11 = 25.$$

Answer (score 0):

hint: $\left(\begin{array}{l} 3 \cr 4 \cr 5\end{array} \right) = 2 \left( \begin{array}{l} 1 \cr 1 \cr 1 \end{array} \right) + \left( \begin{array}{l} 1 \cr 2 \cr 3\end{array}\right).$

determinant is a linear function of every column.